# Use scroll position to toggle visibility of a button, using vanilla JavaScript (no JQuery). Pay attention to performance

Tags: javascript, scroll, toggle, visibility

I have a button to scroll up from bottom of a page:

```
<div id="scroll-to-top">
   <a href="#head">
      <i></i>
   </a>
</div>
```

The essential CSS:

```
#scroll-to-top {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 5%;
  width: 60px;
  display: none;
}

#scroll-to-top.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

I'm looking for a best practice approach to toggle the visibility of the #scroll-to-top button. This should work without any JS-libraries/frameworks, just vanilla JavaScript, and with best possible performance.

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_slide.asp

Comment: Go with what's proven/tested w3 teaches all of this. :)

Answer (score 2):

simple and easy

```js
<script>
  const showButton = () => document.querySelector("#scroll-to-top").classList.add("visible");
  const hideButton = () => document.querySelector("#scroll-to-top").classList.remove("visible");
  document.addEventListener("scroll", (e) => window.scrollY < 100 ? hideButton() : showButton());
</script>
```

Comment: you can optimize this by creating a variable as such
const classList = document.querySelector("#scroll-to-top").classList;
const show = () = classList.add('visible')
const hide= () = classList.remove('visible')

Comment: Thank you guys! I found a similar approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
var lastScrollPos = 0;
var performing = false;

/**
 * show the button #scroll-to-top only
 * on bottom part of the page 
 */
function toggleVisibility(scrollPos, buttonId) {
  if(scrollPos > 500) {
    $(buttonId).addClass('visible');
  }
  else {
    $(buttonId).removeClass('visible');
  }
}


document.addEventListener('scroll', (evt) => {
  
  // just to test how often onScroll fires without throttling
  // it's no more often than every 16ms
  // so setTimeout(myFunction, 16) is senseless
  console.log(performance.now())

  lastScrollPos = window.scrollY;
  if(!performing) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      toggleVisibility(lastScrollPos, '#scroll-to-top');
      performing = false;
    }, 500);
  }
  performing = true;
}, {passive: true}) ;
```

Notes:

with setTimeout(myFunction, 500) we call toggleVisibility() max. every 500ms. To throttle with timeouts about 16ms seems to be senseless because onScroll event fires no more often than every 16ms.

`passive: true`: never prevent scrolling even if event listener performs too long or doesn't execute at all (first scrollen, then event listener)